# How to change register values on Ripi 3 model B

Tags: pi-3, spi

I have an issue with my SPI0 CLK 'pausing' between every byte that is sent from the Pi. I found in this handbook (entered in comments) that I can adjust some register values. Is there a way to do this? Specifically the DLEN register in section 10?

Here's a pic (Note, this pause occurs after every 3 bytes while I was connected to SPI1. I've since changed to SPI0 but the same issue occurs, only after every byte rather than every 3)

[image: Waveform of CLK signal]

Yellow = CS
Blue = clk
Purple = MOSI

Comment: Please edit your question and include the picture not a link to a 3rd party site. This prevents broken images and makes it easier for all to see the problem.

Comment: Handbook: https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

Comment: the link to the pdf belongs in your question too not the comments.